# Столкнулся с циклом в if!

Tags: c#, winforms, циклы, if, условия

Программирую обычный кликер на WinForms. Проблема обширная!

Хотел сделать два режима Advanced/Default и сохранять их.
Создал и сохранял в параметрах переменные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В "**Mode**" я мог бы присвоить тип bool, если у меня только два режима, но это сути дела не меняет! (поменяю потом)

У меня метод, который вызывает новую форму, так называемую "**FormAdvanced**" и скрывает прошлую форму.

```
 void formAdvancedOpen()
        {
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.Mode == "Advanced") 
            {
                FormAdvanced formAdvanced = new FormAdvanced();
                if (formAdvanced != null)
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                    Hide();
                    formAdvanced.Show();
                }
            }
        }
```

Проблема такая, что после проверки условия  `if (Properties.Settings.Default.Mode == "Advanced")` компилятор переходит на другую строчку, где создаётся форма и она возвращается снова к проверке условия, как будто, тут цикл For или While.

**Тут тяжело понять, тут надо видеть!**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно дальше этого места код никуда не идёт.

Если с заходом дебажить, то сперва обращается к  `private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;` в FormAdvanced.Designer.cs
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом переходит в код формы FormAdvanced

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**До инициализации не доходит. И на повторный круг.**

Из-за этого цикла, он создаёт кучу экземпляров формы, которых не видно! Я это понял благодаря трею (notifyicons). Вот скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Часть кода:

**Главная форма | Default**

```
namespace Clicker
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, int dx, int dy, uint dwData, int dwExtraInfo);
        

        public MainForm()
        {
            TopMost = true;

            InitializeComponent();
            formAdvancedOpen();


          ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

**Форма Advanced**

```
namespace Clicker
{
    public partial class FormAdvanced : Clicker.MainForm
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
        private IKeyboardMouseEvents m_Events;



        public FormAdvanced()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

         ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

Как видно ничего криминального! Не знаю, что делать! Возможно ли мне тут помочь?!

Если убрать вызов метода в начале главный формы, то всё почти отлично!
Могу вызвать его без этого бреда выше, только внутри чего-то.

```
 advancedToolStripMenuItem.Click += (s, a) => {
                Properties.Settings.Default.Mode = "Advanced";
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

                formAdvancedOpen();
            };
```

Тут работает всё адекватно!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Могу выложить в GitHub и указать ссылку, если кому интересно! Хотелось бы решить проблему конечно!**

Заранее всем спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Так вы сами зациклили непойми зачем это. Вот тут у вас зачем наследование одной формы от другой? `class FormAdvanced : Clicker.MainForm` Вот и получается у вас для создания `FormAdvanced` инициализируется `MainForm`, которая в своем конструкторе создает новый `FormAdvanced`, а тот опять `MainForm`, и так по кругу.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ааааа, ну и тупая башка! В ПРАВДУ! Сейчас всё исправлю! Большое спасибо!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ААА, большое спасибо! Добавь, как ответ! Я тебя помучу и голос дам!! И снова огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Унаследовал я прошлую форму из-за того, что решил поэкспериментировать (посмотреть) на "Унаследованную форму"!

Comment: От ответа, пожалуй, откажусь, можете опубликовать его самостоятельно.

Comment: Если вопрос решен, а ответа не последует, не думаю что стоит оставлять этот вопрос, ошибка глупая, таких полно у новичков, но пользы для сообщества 0 тем более по заголовку вопроса вообще не ясно что речь о рекурсии)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Моя ошибка. Я унаследовал одну форму к другой `class FormAdvanced : Clicker.MainForm`  Вот и получается для создания FormAdvanced инициализируется MainForm, которая в своем конструкторе создает новый FormAdvanced, а тот опять MainForm, и так по кругу!

Большое спасибо, EvgeniyZ!